# What is the use of OntouchEvent() method?

Tags: android, event-handling, touch-event

From the Event Handling Framework of android I find that this is its mechanism:

Event get catch if the user interacts with the device screen

1. It is stored in a `MotionEvent Object`.
2. Android gives this Object to the Activity `dispatchTouchEvent()` method.
3. This method dispatch event to the listener of activity . if they did not consume it, it go to the biggest parent of activity, for example, linear layout.
4. And this mechanism that every dispatch method, dispatch MotionEvent to the listener of view and if those did not consume it to a child of view.
5. After this MotionEvent object reaches the last view in the hierarchy it goes up in the `OnTouchEvent()` method of child and goes higher to `OnTouchEvent()` of a parent till it reaches to `OnTouchEvent(`) of activity.

If I understand this correct I just want to know what is the purpose of going up of the MotionEvent in OnTouchEvents? We could handle every form of event from a simple click to custom gesture till the MotionEvent object reach the last listener of the last view in the activity. What's the use of `OnTouchEvent()` method and why it must go up to the activity?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch

Comment: Also, take a look at this project: https://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/

Comment: That was a good answer thank you

Comment: Glad to help :)